# Makefile looping files with pattern

Tags: bash, make

In bash, I can do this:

```
for name in sqls/*.{schema,migration}.sql; do
    echo $name; # some operation on the file name
done
```

It would output something like this:

```
sqls/0001.schema.sql
sqls/0002.schema.sql
sqls/0003.migration.sql
sqls/0004.schema.sql
sqls/0006.schema.sql
sqls/0007.schema.sql
```

However, if I put the same loop into a Makefile:

```
names:
    for name in sqls/*.{schema,migration}.sql; do echo $name; done
```

The output become:

```
sqls/*.{schema,migration}.sql
```

How can I do the same thing in a Makefile?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show exactly what you tried in your Makefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to realize that the {...} is a bash construct whilst Makefiles generally launch the sh which does not support the brace expansion feature.

However all's not lost; if you are with GNU Make then you can tell Make 
to use bash by putting this little line `SHELL := bash` at the very top
of your Makefile.

Answer (score 18):

What you want is :

```
names:
    for name in sqls/*.{schema,migration}.sql; do\
        echo $${name};\ # some operation on the file name
    done
```

As explained in the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html), that's the difference between accessing *GNUMake* and *bash* variables. Here's a simple example using both :

```
LIST = one two three
all:
        for i in $(LIST); do \
            echo $$i; \
        done
```

Here `i` is a bash variable, whilst `LIST` is a GNUMake variable.

**In short**, if you need bash to recieve a dollar sign `$`, put a double dollar sign `$$` in your makefile.
(Note that the use of `{}` or `()` is [equivalent in makefiles or bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185607/whats-the-difference-between-parenthesis-and-curly-bracket-syntax-in-ma).)